# Limiting Disk Space Usage For A Process In Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk-space

I need to have an ability to limit a certain process for using too much disk space.

Saw that this can be solved using containers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33013904/how-to-limit-docker-filesystem-space-available-to-containers)).

Is there anyway to do that in a native way? (Ubuntu 16.04) Disk Quotas is the way to go here?

Comment: Quota? – Yes. Also check [project IDs](https://superuser.com/q/1441509/432690).

Comment: Are these project IDs can be handled dynamically on the process level? seems that they are more like a constant configuration.
In the user level quotas i can start a process using a specific user so it can get it limit no?

Comment: Note that if you work through that answer about containers the solution only seems to work for xfs not for ext4.